# asp.net unable to reference variable from code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have done this on other code and it working fine, but for some reason on a new project in VStudio 2017, i can't reference a variable in asp/html from c# code behind. i then started a new test blank asp web project using the about.aspx from it and same thing see code below, i have NO idea why it's not working. i getting "teststring" does not exist in the current context message , BUT it does. am i totally missing something here.

```
ASP/HTML
<%@ Page Title="About" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="About.aspx.cs" Inherits="TestApp.About" %>

<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <h2><%: Title %>.</h2>
    <h3>Your application description page.</h3>
    <p>Use this area to provide additional information.</p>
    <%=teststring %>
</asp:Content>

C# 
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace TestApp

{
    public partial class About : Page

    {
        public string teststring;

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)

        {
            teststring = "test";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What **exact** error does it give you? Is it complaining about `teststring`? Or perhaps `Title`? Did you build the solution?

Comment: If you breakpoint the Page_Load does it actually hit it ?   Are you seeing the "Use this area..." message render to the screen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the `<@ Page ...>` tag at the top of your ASPX, change the value of the attribute `Inherits="TestApp.About"` to `Inherits="TestApp_About"`. Underscore instead of point/period. I was able to replicate the problem.

Comment: so i changed it to _ and rebuild and same thing, then i changed it back to . and rebuild and now it works. weird